# How to get Chinese simplified language from android device programmatically?

Tags: android, localization

I am doing localization of my app in that I want to know the current language from the device. I am getting current language but I don't how to differentiate Chinese simplified and traditional because for both languages I'm getting the same code like "中文".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
```

Gives chinese simplified and traditional

```
中文 (中国)

中文 (台灣)
```